# Best way to send push notifications using parse in chat app?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I currently have a chat feature in my app. Users can send and receive messages. However, when they are not in the app I would prefer to send a push notification that someone responded to them. However, if they are in the app they will likely get the update anyway. Is the best way to handle this to send a push notification every time there is a message sent out and then if they are not in the app I trap it and handle it in:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

and if they are in the app just ignore/or whatever in:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
      didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo 
            fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))handler
```

Or is it possible to detect if the recipient is logged into the app and only send a push if they are not?

Thanks,

David

Comment: Usually you would send your push notification regardless of the other user's status.
What you're mentioned above is correct, yet you can implement a system that will tell you if a user is logged in or not, but why bother?